# CodeFirst Foreign Key to two properties

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

I'd like to use one property as a foreign key to two seperate entities - once as part of a composite foreign key, and once as a single foreign key. Here's a quick example of what I mean:

```
public class ParentEntity{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    String Id {get; set;}
    [Key, Column(Order = 2), ForeignKey("Year")]
    int YearId {get; set;}

    [ForeignKey("YearId")]
    Year Year;
    virtual ICollection<ChildEntity> Children {get; set;}
}

public class ChildEntity{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0), ForeignKey("Parent")]
    String Id {get; set;}
    [Key, Column(Order = 1), ForeignKey("Parent")]
    String ParentId {get; set;}
    [Key, Column(Order = 2), ForeignKey("Parent, Year")]
    int YearId {get; set;}

    [ForeignKey("ParentId, YearId")]
    ParentEntity Parent{get; set;}

    [ForeignKey("YearId")]
    Year Year {get; set;}
}

public class Year{
    [Key]
    int YearId {get; set;}
}
```

The YearId/Year Property in `ChildEntity` should serve as both part of the primary key (ParentId / Year) to `ParentEntity`, and as a foreign key to the `Year` table.

However, the tag `ForeignKey("Parent, Year")` is not valid, because it can only take one parameter to a navigation property. This is the error message I get:

```
Additional information: The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'YearId' on type 'CodeFirst.Models.ChildEntity' is not valid. 
The navigation property 'Parent, Year' was not found on the dependent type 'CodeFirst.Models.ChildEntity'. 
The Name value should be a valid navigation property name.
```

Which I suppose makes sense, it's looking for a navigation property named 'Parent, Year' instead of two navigation properties, named 'Parent' and 'Year'.

How can I force EntityFramework/CodeFirst to recognise this pattern correctly?

NB: I named the entities 'parent' / 'child', but there is no inheritance relation between them (it is in fact an ownership relation).

Comment: Just don't use composite keys. It's an anti-pattern that makes your code unnecessarily complicated, without purpose. The whole point of a primary key is that it's unique. There's no need to combine it with anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You only need the ForeignKeyAttribute on the navigation property *or* the foreign key property.  Not both.  So like this:

```
    public class ParentEntity
    {
        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        public String Id { get; set; }
        [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
        public int YearId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("YearId")]
        Year Year;
        public virtual ICollection<ChildEntity> Children { get; set; }
    }

    public class ChildEntity
    {
        [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
        public String Id { get; set; }
        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        public String ParentId { get; set; }
        [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
        public int YearId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ParentId, YearId")]
        public ParentEntity Parent { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("YearId")]
        public Year Year { get; set; }
    }

    public class Year
    {
        [Key]
        public int YearId { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ParentEntity{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    String Id {get; set;}
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    int YearId {get; set;}

    [ForeignKey("YearId")]
    virtual Year Year;
    virtual ICollection<ChildEntity> Children {get; set;}
}

public class ChildEntity{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    String Id {get; set;} 
    String ParentId {get; set;}
    int YearId {get; set;}
    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    virtual ParentEntity Parent{get; set;}
    [ForeignKey("YearId")]
    virtual Year Year {get; set;}
}

public class Year{
    [Key]
    int YearId {get; set;}
}
```